# PassiveAggressiveClassifier partial_fit giving the same result

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

I have a PassiveAggressiveClassifier and I use partial_fit to train. The data is a collection of materials and each material is a matrix(400x80000) and I flatten it before providing to the fit.

So for example I have aluminum and asphalt, each sample being a csv and I would have 5 samples of each. The problem is that when I try to predict a sample, it always gives the last fitted material.

I also tried with fit but I read that if you do it multiple times, it deletes the old data and overwrites it.

Example code with 3 materials:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sampleFile)    
 flatten_df = df_selected.to_numpy().reshape(1,-1);
clf.partial_fit(flatten_df,[currentMaterialSample],classes=['KAMIEN #1','stone','wood']);
```

And for testing I tried to predict after each fit the Kamien #1. I trained 5 samples of Kamien and it returns Kamien (normal because it doesn't know any other samples) but from just one stone it gives the result stone. Also when it gets to just one sample of wood it returns wood.

How I predict:

```
df = pd.read_csv(KamienSample_001)    
flatten_df = df_selected.to_numpy().reshape(1,-1);
class_code = clf.predict(flatten_df) 
        print("Class code",class_code)
```

Comment: FWIW the n_iter isn't being specified: the number of passes over the training data (aka epochs). Defaults to 5.

Comment: Just changed it to 900 and still not working, also I turned warm_start and is still not making a difference. It shouldn't because it's for fit anyway "warm_start=True,n_iter_no_change=900".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the classifier, changed it to MultinomialNB and is working better, but still needs a lot of samples to get a better result.